# why does servicestack returns 404 Handler for Request not found error?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, servicestack

I have created a Rest Based services in .net 4.5 and hosted the same in IIS7.

I was able to hit the service using HTTP WebRequest (GET,POST) and get the response, But when hit through ServiceStack I get the following error message,

[image]

The code to hit the API in service stack is,

```
    IServiceClient serviceClient = new XmlServiceClient("http://localhost/ServerAccessManagerAPI/events");
    var response = serviceClient.Send(request);
```

I included the following lines in my service config file,

```
  <location>
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

  </location>
```

Can anyone help me on this please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [ServiceStack ServiceClients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) accepts a **BaseUri** which should the **Base Uri** for all your ServiceStack services, and not the url to a specific one. Try instead:

```
var serviceClient = new XmlServiceClient("http://localhost/ServerAccessManagerAPI/");
var response = serviceClient.Send(request);
```